# Speed up CruiseControl.Net

Tags: .net, msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

After tests i noticed that CC runs the same msbuild process slower in 2 times. If i run msbuild with the same parameters from command line i'll have 2 minutes, with CC - 4 minutes. The larger project with 4 minutes build gives me a 8 minutes with CC. So how to speed up CC or what additional operations it executes?

Comment: Are you running the same MSBuild version in both cases? On the same machine? Did you try passing `/m` to it? http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FasterBuildsWithMSBuildUsingParallelBuildsAndMulticoreCPUs.aspx

Comment: sure, i'm talking about ccnet performance instead msbuild

Answer (score 0):

Look at your build log to see how CCNET is spending the time. MSBuild is just one of many operations that CCNET is performing as part of the build.

That being said, there's no real way to see what the cause is without looking at your project's CCNET configuration. Also, where are you doing your manual MSBuild call? If it's not on the CCNET server then your local machine could just be faster and newer than the CCNET server.